# Can't lookup an EJB remote via JNDI under JBoss EAP6

Tags: java, maven, jboss, ejb-3.0, jndi

I am trying to lookup an EJB 3 under Jboss EAP6.
I have a maven EJB project witch named **service-All** where i have tow packages (**interface** and **Impl**) and i have a other java project witch named **ClientEJB**.
This is an example of an interface and it's implementation:

```
@Remote
public IClient{
void showClient(String name);
}
```

The Implementation:

```
@Statless
@Remote(IClient.Class)
public ClientImpl(){
public void showClient(String name){
System.out.println("I'am Mr or Mme"+name);
}
```

About the java prject, this is the main class:

```
public MyClass{

  private IClient client;

  public static void main(String args[]){
    InvockClient().showClient("ClientTest");
  }

  public static IClient InvockClient(){
    final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
      jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
      jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
      Context context;
      IClient client= null;
      try {
          context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
      client=(IUpdateCleRepartition) context.lookup("ejb:service-All/service-All /"+Client.class.getSimpleName()+"!" + IClient.class.getName());
          context.close();
      } catch (NamingException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
      return client;
  }
}
```

This is jboss-ejb-client.properties the witch i have it in the src\main\resources

```
# JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
# Copyright 2012, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
# contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the 
# distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

The service-All.jar is deployed on jboss EAP6  and when i run the main method it gives me this:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:serviceAll, moduleName:serviceAll, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@1629bc56
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:749)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:116)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:253)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:198)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.ShowClient(Unknown Source)
at org.kaml.MyClass.showClient(MyClass.java:12)
at eu.spb.batch.lceb.Launcher.main(MyClass.java:10)
```

Any Idea to solve that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your correct jndi string should be

```
ejb:/service-All/"+Client.class.getSimpleName()+"!" + IClient.class.getName()
```

The first ocurrence of "service-All" you had doesn't belong because you are not packaging your ejb in an ear.

Also, don't forget to pass username and password in your properties

```
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "peter");
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "lois");
```

remember that you have to add the user ("peter" in this example) to your jboss. There's a script for that in jboss-eap-6.0/bin/add-user.sh (or add-user.bat for windows)

Here you can find documentation for remote lookups

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project

Answer (score 0):

my score doesn't allow me to add a comment so i'm writing an answer. In addition to what @mendieta suggested you can check if your ejb(ejb:service-All/service-All) is deployed correctly in boot.log

If you are doing a remote lookup, you would have to pass the Context.PROVIDER_URL as well in the jndi properties. You can read more about that [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project?_sscc=t)

Answer (score 0):

this is the right way:

```
ejb:/service-All/"+Client.class.getSimpleName()+"!" + IClient.class.getName()
```